# Send keys through telnet

Tags: key, telnet, webbbs

I'm trying to figure out a source code. It's an application that connect to a BBS through telnet. And it specifies a key_up by sending \033[A, key_pageup by 033[5~. I wonder what rule it use. Is that some kind of encoding or something belongs to telnet protocol? And how about sending a space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).